# ncurses: How to check the mouse left or right button clicked?

Tags: python, ncurses

consider this program:

```
import _curses # _curses.pyd supplied locally for python27 win32
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
#curses.noecho() 
curses.curs_set(0)
screen.keypad(1)
curses.mousemask(curses.ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS)

screen.addstr("This is a Sample Curses Script\n\n")

key=0
while key!=27: # Esc to close
    key = screen.getch()
    #screen.erase()
    if key == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
        _, mx, my, _, bstate = curses.getmouse()
        if bstate & curses.BUTTON1_CLICKED:
            screen.addstr(" left was clicked")
        else:
            screen.addstr(" right was clicked")
        screen.refresh()

screen.endwin()
```

I tried it in linux, however it does't show the clicked button correctly, sometimes it shows it correctly and sometimes not. I noticed that `bstate` for right button is less than 10. It's exactly 4, but bstate is sometimes 4, sometimes 2, etc. And for left button it's above 1000. Can I use this observation to get the clicked button?

Comment: This is not Linux-specific, please read the description of the tag that you applied. However, it may be specific to the shell and terminal you're using.

Comment: The logic of the if-else statement is wrong. If the left button was not clicked, it does not mean the right one was clicked. There are many other event types `getevent` can return in addition to those two mentioned.

Comment: correction: `getmouse`, not getevent

Comment: The left button is usually button1.

Comment: @VPfB I know but it's mainly for test, the problem is that it doesn't work for left button...

Comment: @Ahmad Please be more specific. "Doesn't work" is not very helpful. Write what you have expected and what happened instead. Otherwise we can only guess. E.g. maybe you wanted to test for `BUTTON1_PRESSED` bit instead of `.. CLICKED`.

Comment: @VPfB the question title is streightforward, do you know any workable script to detect mouse clicks? did you test the script I sent? However, I found a solution and posted it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this script to detect the left and right click:

```
import _curses # _curses.pyd supplied locally for python27 win32
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
#curses.noecho() 
curses.curs_set(0) 
screen.keypad(1) 
curses.mousemask(curses.ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS)

screen.addstr("This is a Sample Curses Script\n\n") 

key=0
while key!=27: # Esc to close
    key = screen.getch()
    #screen.erase()
    if key == curses.KEY_MOUSE:
        _, mx, my, _, bstate = curses.getmouse()
        y, x = screen.getyx()
        if (bstate & curses.BUTTON1_PRESSED != 0 or
                bstate & curses.BUTTON1_CLICKED != 0):
            screen.addstr(my, mx, "left was clicked")
        elif (bstate & curses.BUTTON3_PRESSED != 0 or
                bstate & curses.BUTTON3_CLICKED != 0):
            screen.addstr(my, mx, "right was clicked")
    screen.refresh()

curses.endwin()
```